# is 'envy your traveling life' correct sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have an Australian friend who travels very often and I want to say to her

> I really envy your traveling life

Is it right sentence? If not, what is nicer words?

Comment: No, it's not correct. Life doesn't travel.

Comment: I think it's OK.  *Traveling* is being used as a participial adjective; it describes a *life of traveling*.

Comment: I am sure you were perfectly understood. I'd say, "I envy you your life as a traveler." Or, "I envy that you travel so often/ as much as you do."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct and sounds perfectly clear to me, but I think it would maybe sound a bit better if you said "lifestyle" instead of "life", as you're describing the way that they choose to live their life.

> I envy your travelling lifestyle.

Comment: In this case, the use of `life` can be confusing. While a nice listener would understand the intention clearly, the raw meaning is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is correct. You can also say, "I really envy that you get to travel so much."

Answer (score 0):

As a sentence your text is OK.

However ["envy"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/envy) can be seen as a negative thing, similar to jealousy.

I might alternatively say:
"You are very lucky to travel so much"

Comment: In this case, you may consider it "white envy", it is not negative.